# tfs work items can not be modified after user is renamed in Active Directory

Tags: tfs

TFS stores information about who created or who activated a work item and for some reason checks its validity whenever the work item is modified.

When a user is deleted from active directory or renamed in active directory, all work items even slightly has connection with the user can not be modified. Usually the error message is something like ...
TF20015: The field 'Activated By' contains the value 'blah blah blah' that is not in the list of supported values.

I've found a [blogpost](http://dweisz.wordpress.com/2008/09/03/problems-in-tfs-2008-when-an-ad-user-was-renamed/) which recommends tweaking the TFS database, which is something not supported nor recommended by Microsoft.

What can be done to resolve this?

Thanks...

e-mre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caveat:  I'm not sure that this will work, and right now I'm not in a position to test it.  However, I've had success with this approach on some other fields.

If you use the TFS Power Tools to edit the work item type definition, you should be able to change the Activated By field's rules and add an `ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE` rule to it.  This *might* allow you to save those records when the AD name changes.

We've used this with some success with the Assigned To field.

Comment: Seems like a bit of a blunt instrument (changing the work item template) for what must be a fairly common problem. People change their names, or leave organisations all the time. I'd be interested in seeing if this approach works as my solution is very manual. With luck one of the MS guys will see this question and offer a more elegant solution than either of ours :-)

Comment: I also feel a little uncomfortable with modifying the work item template for something that I believe should be solved in another way.  Nevertheless, I tried it and it works, thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this behaviour. It occurs if someone who activated a work item is removed from Active Directory (leaves the company) or if they change their name (gets married).

It's simple to fix, you just need to change the work item status from `Active` to `Pending` then back to `Active` this will change the "Activated By" field to the person chaging the status and the problem will be resolved.

Are you using TFS 2008? I seem to remember that this issue is fixed in 2010 (but I might have dreamt that)

If you have a lot of work items [this blog](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/08/31/Renamed-or-deleted-AD-user-prevents-work-item-to-save.aspx) might have a solution that helps automate the fix.

Comment: It breaks my heart to say that I am using TFS 2010 and still having the problem. Looks like it wasn't fixed. 

The solution proposed in the blogpost is promising but it also is for TFS 2008. I am using powertools March 2011 edition and there is no tfsusers.exe in that package.

Any updated solution ?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Did you try chaging the status manualy? This should solve the problem although I admit it's not great if you have a lot of work items that need updating. Robaticus's answer may be of use but chaging the work item template seems like an extreme way to solve what must be a fairly common problem.

Comment: I e-mailed the blogger, Ewald Hofman, about the issue, saying there is no tfusers.exe in TFS 2010 power tools. We had a little chat and he proposed the use of TFSConfig.exe (while noting he didn't have a change to try it himself) but it seems it is no solution either. TFSConfig.exe helps to move user account references to another domain but no luck on renaming them.